# Can it possible to add the custom fields under Details tab liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-aui

With reference to the following link, https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+Fields+and+JSP+Hooks I am able to add the custom fields. But by default the newly added custom fields are showing under the "Custom Fields" tab. But I need to display my custom fields under the "Details" tab. How can I do that. Any suggestions please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to hook the JSP of the portlet that you are working on. For example if you are working on Journal article portlet, than you will have to hook the JSPs in TOMCAT/.../html/portlet/journal/article/...jsp and make the changes in these JSPs as per your need.
Hope it help