# Issue with customizing user administration in liferay portal

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-aui

I wanted to do some enhancements in the forms used for adding and editing the users. In my requirement I am using only sites so I don't want to use Organizations and User groups sections. I want to hide some sections in the user creation and editing forms. With reference to some web search I have created the properties-ext.properties file with following content

```
users.form.my.account.main=details,password,sites,roles
users.form.my.account.identification=addresses,phone-numbers 
users.form.my.account.miscellaneous=announcements,comments
```

After restarting the tomcat, The changes are reflected only at "My Account" tab. But I want to reflect the same changes in user creation and user edit forms also. How can I do that? Are there any specific configuration is there to do the same Or did I miss some steps? Or If we want to do enhancements through Hooks, Where can I find the source code files for add and edit user forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are portal properties to set which sections you want in User Add/Edit screen.

```
#
# Input a list of sections that will be included as part of the user form
# when adding a user.
#
users.form.add.main=details,organizations,personal-site
users.form.add.identification=
users.form.add.miscellaneous=

#
# Input a list of sections that will be included as part of the user form
# when updating a user.
#
users.form.update.main=details,password,organizations,sites,user-groups,roles,personal-site,categorization
users.form.update.identification=addresses,phone-numbers,additional-email-addresses,websites,instant-messenger,social-network,sms,open-id
users.form.update.miscellaneous=announcements,display-settings,comments,custom-fields
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you. I have few more queries which I have updated as new questions. Please give me some suggestion If you have any idea on the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262168/issue-with-site-administrator-page-level-access-permissions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256685/can-it-possible-to-add-the-custom-fields-under-details-tab-liferay

Comment: Where can I find the front end source code for User Add and Edit screens? Can you please tell me the path for these files in the liferay source bundle. Please...

Comment: `portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\users_admin\edit_user.jsp` and jsp-files under folder `portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\users_admin\user`

Comment: Will the add and edit screen jsp files are same? I am able to see the edit_user.jsp. What about add screen?

Comment: same file is used for Add/Edit User screen

Comment: Hi I add a new label "users.form.update.miscellaneous= salary" but when I click on this its showing blank. could you please suggest how can I use this link. I don't want to use custom field please suggest with jsp hook.

Comment: You have to create respective jsp for salary (salary.jsp), you may look into folder structure(docroot\html\portlet\users_admin\user) and you will get idea